# php Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php

i get the error on the line 2, below

don't know why ... seems fine to me ... i've tried numerous ways of doing it, but the same error comes up
any ideas ?

Any help would be much appreciated ...

Basically i have an input box with a submit button and whats submitted into the box is then printed on the same page, right under the submit box.

The code is fine when i remove the html tags. don't understand why, but it happens ...

```
echo "<h2>Input:</h2>";
echo . "<div class='blank'>".$convert."</div>" ;
```

Comment: Unexpected what?  Maybe `.`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `.` before the start of your string. That will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<h2>Input:</h2>";
echo "<div class='blank'>".$convert."</div>";
```